# Xbox One Saved Data - How to retain saved data after uninstall

Tags: xbox-one

My storage is almost full and I need to uninstall some of my games.

Some games I play have just the game size whereas other gave the game size as well as "Saved Data".

What I want to do is uninstall some games but keep all of my saved data for when I go back to those games.

I assume that for games that have reserved space for saved data; as long as I only uninstall the game without touching the saved data then i should retain my saved data.

Though, some games I play don't have any reserved space for saved data which makes me believe that if I uninstall those games I'll lose all of my saved data.

Comment: Save data used and synced online is stored online. As long as you put each game online first to syncronise your data there should be saves on the cloud. I'll test it in the next few days. Stuck at work for the night.

Answer (score 2):

All save game saves are automatically synced with the cloud. According to the [Xbox Support](http://support.gtm.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/games/cloud-game-saves-faq) site:

> How do I sync my saved games to the cloud?
>
> Your saved games are automatically stored in the cloud while you’re
>   connected to Xbox Live. You don’t have to select cloud storage. If you
>   sign in to a different Xbox One console, your saves will be recovered
>   and accessible from that console as soon as you sign in with your Xbox
>   Live profile.

Answer (score 0):

All of the Xbox One game saves are separate from the game install file.  Not sure why some of your games do not give you any option for dealing with the game saves, but you will be fine when you download the game again.  Also, as others have mentioned, as long as you are connected to the internet while playing, you're game saves should be uploaded to the cloud.  If you have no save data and turn that game on again, it will bring up a prompt asking if you want to load your save data from the cloud.